# Parameterization of a part of a cylinder

Tags: surfaces, parametrization

I have to find the parameterization of the surface that is part of the cylinder
$$y^{2}=2-x$$
for $x\geq0$, bounded by the cylinders:
$$y^{2}=z\quad\text{and}\quad y=z^{3}$$
for $0\leq y\leq1$.

I could draw the surface and I can see it. I tried to write $x$ and $z$ as functions of $y$ (or $x$ and $y$ using $z$), but for me is, for example:
$$z=y^{2}$$
and
$$z=\sqrt[3]{y}$$
How could I work with it? Which one should I use?
(Sorry for the English)

Answer (score 1):

The surface is $y^2 = 2-x. $  The rest of it establishes the boundaries of the surface.

One way to do it would be:

$x = 2-y^2\\
y = y\\
z = z$

With $0\le y \le 1$ and $y^2 <z<\sqrt [3] y$